# Do I need to pre-register a UK electric vehicle to drive in low emissions zones in the Netherlands and Germany?

Tags: germany, driving, netherlands

I'm planning to drive my UK-registered electric vehicle in the Netherlands and Germany. I may (by design or accident!) drive in a low emissions zone in either country. Do I need to have a sticker on the car, or do these only apply to petrol/diesel cars?

Comment: Incidentally, in the Netherlands, the restrictions only impact diesel cars. Petrol cars are fine too, no matter how old or inefficient they might be.

Comment: Does the car have an E license plate or an E sticker?

Comment: @MarkJohnson it has the UK "green slash" on the number plate.

Comment: Yes, that would be the equivalent of the german plate with an **E** at the end. The next question is then if any of the local police know what that means.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5946/where-can-i-buy-the-german-environmental-badge-while-driving-to-my-destination-i?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**In Germany, the answer is yes**: If an area is restricted you need a sticker (“Umweltplakette”) even if your vehicle is electric and obviously qualifies. Comments mentioned the fact that you can order it online and some exceptions for cars with another national sticker or special number plates but you definitely need a marker of some sort. Otherwise, you will have to locate some certification bureau that can issue the sticker. It's been a long time since I did it but as far as I know you get a sticker on the spot for a small fee, based on the car's registration papers. You do have to plan for 15 minutes and check their opening hours (the most annoying thing if you travel on a week-end).

**In the Netherlands, there is no sticker and you do not have to do anything in advance**. Enforcement is fully automated for Dutch number plates and you can check online if your car qualifies. For foreign number plates, it's up to you to check the rules and enforcement is obviously more difficult but if your car does qualify, you can simply drive in the restricted area without any formalities. Exact restrictions vary depending on the city but for cars, they only impact diesel engines and an electric vehicle obviously qualifies.

Comment: *only with a green sticker could it be determined "at first glance" in a simple way and by personnel with no further training whether a vehicle was allowed to drive in the inner cities* https://twitter.com/alex_avoigt/status/1440356423469199364

Comment: Addendum from someone who recently bought a Umweltplakette for Germany: You can order them online and they send it to you in the mail (I'm in Switzerland). Just expect it to take a couple of days.

Comment: @Wolter I added a sentence about that, thanks!

Comment: That may not be needed if the car has a *foreign E license plate or a foreign E sticker*: See:
[Foreign-registered Vehicles - Berlin.de](https://www.berlin.de/sen/uvk/en/environment/air/low-emission-zone/foreign-registered-vehicles/) ...

Comment: ... and [File:Plakettenmuster für elektrisch betriebene Fahrzeuge gemäß Anlage 3a (zu § 9a Absatz 4 FZV).svg - Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Plakettenmuster_f%C3%BCr_elektrisch_betriebene_Fahrzeuge_gem%C3%A4%C3%9F_Anlage_3a_(zu_%C2%A7_9a_Absatz_4_FZV).svg): By validly affixing this sticker to the rear of an electric vehicle, which is registered abroad and that has **neither** a *foreign E license plate nor a foreign E sticker*, since September 26, 2015, the same privileges can be claimed in Germany as with an electric vehicle registered in Germany.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Good to know but that seems mostly of academic interest. What is this beast? Does that mean a French sticker that reads "E" would be recognised no matter the design? This looks very much like a variant of the German sticker and a peculiarly German system, not something I have seen anywhere else.

Comment: Unfortunatley the information on this topic is very scanty. As stated in your answer, this must be checked city by city (I found no summery) if exempted from the Umweltplakette. It does offer other advantages. [Alle Plaketten in Europa – Blaue-Plakette.de](https://www.blaue-plakette.de/hr/hintergrundinformationen/alle-plaketten-in-europa.html) and [The advantages of the E-Badge – E-Plakette.eu](https://www.e-plakette.eu/en/general-information/the-advantages-of-the-e-badge.html#c20669)

Comment: >You do have to plan for 15 minutes   Depending on the city/location of that office it could also be 4 hours waiting and only available with a pre-booked appointment (especially during covid)

Comment: @Relaxed French stickers have numbers, not letters, and the notation is opposite of the German one (1 is the best and 5 is the worst). The equivalent of the "E" sticker is a car with a charging cord icon. I'm pretty sure it won't do in Germany. Perhaps you should replace "a marker of some sort" with "a Germany-approved marker".

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Shows French stickers (**E**, then 1-5): [Alle Plaketten in Europa – Blaue-Plakette.de](https://www.blaue-plakette.de/hr/hintergrundinformationen/alle-plaketten-in-europa.html)

Comment: @MarkJohnson It's funny how German idea of French stickers differs from what France actually has: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crit%27air

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Or maybe they took it from a french source, such as here: [PDF - Vandœuvre - vandoeuvre.fr](https://www.vandoeuvre.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/54500_107_BD.pdf)